# General term of the sequence $0,4,9,13,17,22,26,30,\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, generating-functions

> Find the general term of the sequence $0,4,9,13,17,22,26,30,35,39,\cdots$

My try:

If we collect the successive differences, we get a nice sequence $$4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4....$$

It is evident that the general term $a(n)$ of the above sequence is of the form:
$$a(3k+2)=5,a(3k)=a(3k+1)=4$$

With this can we get a closed form general term of the original sequence?

Comment: No, I don't think that this is evident. The sequence could continue completely different.

Comment: If that pattern of differences continues then yes there is closed form result essentially $\frac{13}{3}n$ rounded to the nearest integer and you can deal with that using a multiple of $\sin(\frac{2\pi}{3}n)$

Comment: Hint: if the pattern continues, your original sequence (let's call it $b(n)$) has $b(n+3) = b(n) + 13$.  Again there are cases for $3k$, $3k+1$ and $3k+2$.

Comment: The end result is that from the information of $0,4,9,13,17,22,\dots$ alone there is not enough to go on to uniquely identify the sequence.  You can of course ask about how to simplify the sequence where the differences *are* known or assumed to follow the pattern you describe, but such an assumption is invalid and won't necessarily reflect reality.

Comment: Assuming the sequence continues "as expected". Let $t(n)$ be the $n^{\text{th}}$ term, then if $n = 3k$, $t(n) = 13k$, if $n = 3k+1$, $t(n) = 13k + 4$ and if $n = 3k+2$ then $t(n) = 13k + 9$. You could write this as follows: Let $n = 3k + a$ with $0 \leq a < 3$, then $t(n) = 13k + \frac{a}{2}(a+7)$

Comment: @all please assume sequence continues the same pattern.

Comment: Friends, if we don't assume the sequence continues similarly any time a sequence problem is presented, then the entire mathematical endeavor of pattern-finding will have to be tossed to the winds. I think we all know that any incomplete sequence is not necessarily well-defined. Yet real mathematicians really do this with incomplete sequences all the time, because there *might* be a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence, at least for the known terms, can be modelled by: for $n\ge 0$,
$$a_n=5n-\left\lfloor \frac{2n+1}{3}\right\rfloor$$

Answer (score 1):

We can derive the original sequence from the sequence of differences by reverting the process. Looking at the table below
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c|rrrrrrrrrrr}
n&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&\cdots\\
\hline
a_n&4&5&4&4&5&4&4&5&4&4&\cdots\tag{1}\\
b_n&0&4&9&13&17&22&26&30&35&39&\cdots
\end{array}
\end{align*}
we derive the following equality chain
\begin{align*}
a_1&=\Delta b_1=b_2-b_1\\
a_2&=\Delta b_2 = b_3-b_2\\
a_3&=\Delta b_3=b_4-b_3\\
&\ \vdots\\
a_{n-1}&=\Delta b_{n-1}=b_n-b_{n-1}
\end{align*}
and obtain by adding up the lines
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k=b_n-b_1\qquad\quad n\geq 2}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> From (1) we take $b_1=0$ as starting values and with the relation
> \begin{align*}
> a(3k+2)=5,a(3k)=a(3k+1)=4
> \end{align*}
> we obtain from (2) for $n\geq 2$
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{b_n}&=b_1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k\\
> &=0+\sum_{{k=1}\atop{k\equiv 0(3)}}^{n-1}4
> +\sum_{{k=1}\atop{k\equiv 1(3)}}^{n-1}5+\sum_{{k=1}\atop{k\equiv 2(3)}}^{n-1}4\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=4\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{3}\right\rfloor+5\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor+4\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{3}\right\rfloor}
> \end{align*}

*Note:* In (2) we use telescoping which is based upon a (convenient) sum of differences:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_{k}=\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\Delta} b_k=b_n-b_1\qquad\quad n\geq 2
\end{align*}